# ActiveMQ Prometheus Metrics like enque deque count for monitoring

Tags: activemq-classic, prometheus

How to get Prometheus metrics related to ActiveMQ for an application like enqueue dequeue count from client to host and vice versa and how to set that config file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ActiveMQ "Classic" then you'll need to configure the [Prometheus JMX exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter). It even has an example [ActiveMQ configuration](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/blob/master/example_configs/activemq.yml).

If you're using [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) then you can use this [Artemis Prometheus Metrics Plugin](https://github.com/jbertram/artemis-prometheus-metrics-plugin). Metrics and metrics plugins are discussed in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/metrics.html).